# Logging into the file in Mule ESB

Tags: esb, mule

Can logging be done into the file in MULE ESB?.If so,please give me some examples and code snippets.Thanks in advance

Narayanan

Comment: Cross-posted (and answered) here: http://mule.1045714.n5.nabble.com/Logging-into-the-file-td5450163.html

Answer (score 3):

You need to put log4j properties in your mule project inside main/resources directory. Here's sample log4j.xml that I am using with mule esb.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] [%c] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="ERROR" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
    </filter>
</appender>
<appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="${mule.home}/logs/test.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%t] [%c] - %m%n" />
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
        <param name="LevelMin" value="INFO" />
        <param name="LevelMax" value="FATAL" />
        <param name="AcceptOnMatch" value="true" />
    </filter>
</appender>
<root>
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below log4j.xml file. Name the files as log4j.xml place it in the mule project classpath so that mule will pick this file when starting the app.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
    <param name="File" value="c:/logs/gid/gid.log" />
    <param name="DatePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%t] %C{2} (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Hope this helps you.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can save the entire logs in a file in any location. For that change the target(give the path where you want) in te log4j.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Since Mule 3.6 they changed the Log System from Log4j to Log4j2. Use the following content for your `log4j2.xml` file. Has been tested with Mule 3.8.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%-5p %d [%t] %c: %m%n"/>
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <!-- CXF is used heavily by Mule for web services -->
    <AsyncLogger name="org.apache.cxf" level="WARN"/>
    <!-- Apache Commons tend to make a lot of noise which can clutter the log-->
    <AsyncLogger name="org.apache" level="WARN"/>
    <!-- Reduce startup noise -->
    <AsyncLogger name="org.springframework.beans.factory" level="WARN"/>
    <!-- Mule classes -->
    <AsyncLogger name="org.mule" level="INFO"/>
    <AsyncLogger name="com.mulesoft" level="INFO"/>
    <AsyncRoot level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </AsyncRoot>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```